# Scrollable in my component

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, nokia-s40

I can not set scrollale for center component. But NORTH and SOUTH have to be fixed.

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.setScrollable(false);
this.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, top);
scrollWrap.setScrollable(true);
this.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollWrap);
this.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottom);
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this code is in a subclass of Form? What specifically isn't working? Do you intend to enable scrolling on both X & Y? Are you adding components into the container? Scroll will only work if you add components into the scrollWrap container

Comment: Yes, it is subclass of Form. I add in scrollWrap some continers and want scrollWrap is scrollable. But it isn't work. I NORTH and SOUTH is normal but CENTER is partially visible.

Comment: Did you try setScrollableY(). Did you invoke this code on the EDT? What exactly are you seeing? I suggest you use screenshots to illustrate your issue